# How to pass List of Lists parameter in JPA native query

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to create a JPA native query relevant to the example below:

```
select * from inventory where (server, product) in (('server1','product1'), ('server2','product2'), ('server1','product3'));
```

I have created a native query:

```
@Query(
            value = "select server, product from inventory where (server, product) in (:myList)",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<Product> getProducts(List<List<String>> myList);
```

But when I pass List of Lists as an argument:

```
List<List<String>> myList= Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("server1","product1"),
    Arrays.asList("server2","product2"),
    Arrays.asList("server1","product3")
);
List<Product> products = myRepository.getProducts(myList);
```

I get an error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

I use Oracle database. Please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

This question is **not about passing a flat List** into a native query to filter db results by 1 column (this works fine) but how to pass **a list of nested lists** into a query to filter db results by 2 columns.

Comment: What happens when you replace `(:myList)` with `?`

Comment: If I write: "... in ?" I get java.lang.NullPointerException: null

If I write "... in ?1" I get the same error as before:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed, it's a different problem than the other question... You want to pass a List of Lists, not a List of types that Jpa easily knows how to unpack :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@Query("select server, product from inventory where (server, product) in (:myList)",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<Product> getProducts(@Param("myList") List<List<String>> myList);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator